# Is Magento 2's cart price rule free shipping only applicable on table rate shipping method?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I have created a Custom Shipping method and I just noticed that the free shipping cart price rule is not applying.

While doing some trial and error, it turns out that the cart price rule will only be applied to the table rate shipping method and not on other shipping methods like flat rate.

This leads me to my question, is Magento 2's cart price rule free shipping is only applicable on table rate shipping method?

If so, how can I apply the cart price rule free shipping on my custom shipping method?

Comment: so you want to apply custom shipping which works like magento's free shipping method. am I right ?

Comment: No, I built a custom shipping method that calculates shipping rates. It's working fine, however, the cart price rule that I created under marketing were not applied.

I created a cart price rule which works like this, "Buy 250 or more of X product then Get Free Shipping"